# NSString with date: reduce size of date

Tags: iphone, date, ios5, nsstring

I have a NSString like `Mon Feb 06 20:02:17 +0000 2012`. I want to write it in a shorter way, maybe like: `DD-MM-YY, HH:MM`. I have think that maybe I can convert it to NSDate and again to a shorter NSString, but I don't know how to convert this strange date format to NSDate.

If you need more information, ask me.
Thanks!

Comment: Check it out: [parsing date formats in cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399527/parsing-unsupported-date-formats-in-via-cocoas-nsdate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an `NSDateFormatter` to tell `NSDate` the format the original date is in and the format you want it in, then you can convert between the two like this:

```
NSString *oldDate = @"Mon Feb 06 20:02:17 +0000 2012";
NSString *oldFormat = @"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZ yyyy";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:oldFormat];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sourceString];

NSString *newFormat = @"dd-MM-yy, HH:mm";

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:newFormat];
NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 3):

There are similar question and answers in StackOverflow and a tutorial that may help you:

Tutorial:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-3.html

Similar questions:

- [NSString to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)
- [Convert NSString->NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154477/convert-nsstring-nsdate)
- [How to convert NSDate to NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546859/how-to-convert-nsdate-to-nsstring)
- [Convert NSString of a date to an NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332319/convert-nsstring-of-a-date-to-an-nsdate)

**EDIT**

```
NSString *dateStr = @"20081122"; 

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Since you know the exact date format, it will be easier. I edited my answer to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can convert to NSDate using one of its method:

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string
```

And then convert that to whatever you want using NSDateFormatter.

Edit: Actually NSDate has a class method so you may check that as well:

```
+ (id)dateWithString:(NSString *)aString
```

Comment: I know it but I have try it and NSDate gives nil